# Nodejs How to check path of require "module name"?

Tags: node.js, import, node-modules, require

I am debugging issue kind of "can not find  moudule 'x'"

for do that i want to know the actual path that node trying to resolve my module.

```
require.resolve("X")
```

This gives me actual path of resolved "X"

**But the problem is**
if "X" is not found
it dose not give me the
**tried path**

Comment: `node_modules/X` will be the path most likely

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski. ah... but that is weird, I double checked node_modules/X is exist actually in my folder. why am i get that error humm....

Comment: I don't understand, if does not return the tried path? but if X not found, it returns an error (with the path included)

Comment: @Rami Dridi
you mean Error object include track paths ?